# Java primitive object instanciation: heap or not?

Tags: java, heap-memory, instantiation

So I was reading this book where it says that if I create a class Point and then instantiate it by doing `Point p1 = new Point();` then I will have:

- a Point object on the heap (as a result of the "new" keyword);
- a reference to this object (p1);
- and when an object has no references then it can be disposed by the garbage collector.

I guess I got the meaning, but it got me thinking. What happens "memory-wise" with primitive types and strings, i.e. what is the difference between:

```
 - int x1 = 100;
 - String s1 = "hello";
```

and

```
 - int x2 = new Integer(100);
 - String s2 = new String("hello");
```

In the first case, are '100' and 'hello' going to be instantiated and stored on the heap? Else, what are x1 and s1 referencing?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate: [Does the Java primitives go on the Stack or the Heap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646632/does-the-java-primitives-go-on-the-stack-or-the-heap)

Comment: A String is not a primitive, neither an `Integer`. But an `int` is.

Comment: I know, that is why I made the distinction "primitive types and strings", and my question is particularly oriented on x1 and s1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

```
 int x2 = new Integer(100);
```

This means an `Integer` object is created, outboxed (the JVM returns its `intValue`) and `100` assigned to an `int` primitive. The `Integer` object is no longer referenced and can be disposed (of course maybe the JIT can optimize that to `int x2 = 100`).

I assume you are talking about local variables, because attributes are part of the object and so lie with it in the heap.

```
 int x1 = 100;
```

An int variable is declared in the stack and assigned a value

```
 String s1 = "Hello";
```

An String object is created (or referenced, see `String.intern()`) and a pointer is added to the stack.

The other possibilities are exactly the same.

Comment: thank you, it makes it much clearer. One more question (but maybe it would deserve an own post):
- what about methods belonging to an object? are they also on the heap with it? I am having a hard time figuring out how the memory of my programs is "organised"...

Comment: Methods are part of the class definition (which is by itself an object of class `java.lang.Class`). When you load the class A, the object `Class A` is created with all the method info, but when you instantiate an object of class A its methods do not need extra space. When you execute one of the objects methods, the JVM goes to the `Class A` object and retrieves the code for it from it, not from each instance of A.

Answer (score 1):

local primitives will be put onto the stack, but a member field of an object will be put on the heap with that object (whether it is primitive or not). Some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646632/does-the-java-primitives-go-on-the-stack-or-the-heap).

strings are objects and exist on the heap. They do work a little differently though, some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881922/questions-about-javas-string-pool).

Answer (score 0):

Both S1 and S2 will create new memory references where the value is stored. Primitive data types may refer to a stack or to a heap depending on to circumstances. You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099695/java-array-is-stored-in-stack-or-heap)